# Aggregate function within Sum case when

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to have my then statement be a count of a specific column and it is not working. When I choose then 1 else 0, it is counting encounters and I want it to count unique patients regardless of how many encounters they have had.

```
select 
sum (case when soc.tobacco_user_c in (1, 2, 4, 5) then 1 (**want to have this be
                                                            count(pat.pat_id - which is
                                                            varchar**)
                                                  else 0 end) Compliant
,sum(case when soc.tobacco_user_c in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) then 1 else 0 end) TotalEligible,
dep.DEPARTMENT_NAME

from table 1 enc
inner join table2 soc on enc.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = soc.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID 
inner join table3 ser2 on enc.pcp_prov_id = ser2.prov_id
inner join table4 dep on ser2.PRIMARY_DEPT_ID = dep.DEPARTMENT_ID
inner join patient table5 pat on enc.pat_id = pat.pat_id
where dep.department_id in ('100501201', '100502502', '100504501', '100607501', '100801804', '100801809', '200101101', 
'200201201', '200401401', '2013011301', '2016011601')
group by dep.DEPARTMENT_NAME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `COUNT` with a `DISTINCT` on the field that you want to count:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN soc.tobacco_user_c IN (1, 2, 4, 5) THEN pat.pat_id END) AS Compliant
```

Comment: it's giving an error that conversion failed when converting varchar to data type int

Comment: I still had the else in my statement. I reread yours and corrected and it worked. Thank you!!!